# List of the Intents in Android music players

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player

Is there anywhere with a list of the Intents different players send out metadata on a track change? Ex: Sense uses:

```
com.htc.music.metachanged
```

Looking for 3rd-party (non-bundled) players and the default player.

tks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'list' with the intents of all music players. For the default you can check the documentation and for those that are open sourced you can check the code, but unfortunately in all other cases (3rd-party players) there is nothing you can do. You can write your own player and use whatever Intents you wish.

Comment: It's a problem for me because the media player don't send a Intent to inform other applications about some informations like track number, album, author, music name. In the iPhone since it have only one media player it sends this information automatic, I wanted this in Android.

Comment: Yes but i can't - as you said itunes is the only media player on Iphone so they have full control over it. In the other hand there are many players for android from different developers which can't be synchronized.